# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (41,) and (1, 41)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to plot a vs kappa_inv and I keep getting the error: ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (41,) and (1, 41).

I saw a prev post about changing plt.plot square brackets to round ones but the error is still occurring. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
import numpy

L = [20,20, 20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]
L = numpy.array(L)
delta = [0.5, 0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5]
delta = numpy.array(delta)
x = L/delta

a =[-0.5,0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5,6,6.5,7,7.5,8,8.5,9,9.5,10,10.5,11,11.5,12,12.5,13,13.5,14,14.5,15,15.5,16,16.5,17,17.5,18,18.5,19,19.5]
numpy.array(a)
#Force
F = 100 #kN

#calc sigma
y = 250 #mm
E = 32800 #MPa
I =1.837E9 #mm4
sig = y/(E*I)
print (sig)

kappa = []
b = []
y = 20
while y >= 0: 
   b.append(y)
   y = y-0.5
   numpy.array(b)
for val in a:
    val = "{:.1f}".format(val)
    val = float(val)
    fraction = b/L

kappa_i = fraction * val

kappa.append(kappa_i)
b = b - delta

N = 4
Length = len(kappa)
pad_kappa = numpy.pad(kappa,(0,N),'constant', constant_values = 0)
print(pad_kappa)

#Calc bending moment list
BM = []
for k in range (0,Length):
    bendingMoment = (pad_kappa[k]*F) + (pad_kappa[k+3]*F)
    BM.append(bendingMoment)
    print(BM)

Strain =[]
for j in range(0,len(BM)):
    strain = (BM[j] * sig) * 10E6
    Strain.append(strain)

kappa_inv = [ -x for x in kappa]
numpy.array(kappa_inv)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(a,kappa_inv)
plt.ylabel('KAPPA')
plt.xlabel('LENGTH ALONG BEAM')
plt.show()

#E = BM*10E6 * sigma
strainCalcReverse = []
for s in Strain:
    bendYourMomLOL = s/sig * (1/10E6)
    bendYourMomLOL.append(strainCalcReverse)

print(strainCalcReverse)
```

Comment: Is your expected output graph a diagonal ?

Comment: `numpy.array(a)` does nothing unless you assign back to `a`.

Comment: You should **know** what each line in your code does or produces.. Guesses or assumptions don't count

Comment: `plt.plot(a,kappa_inv[0])`?

Comment: Which line has the error?  Full traceback if necessary.

Comment: This looks like python list code, with an incomplete numpy overlay.  Did you read any numpy basics?

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of messy stuff in your code,

Lines like:

```
numpy.array(a)          # doesn't change list a
numpy.array(b)          # same
```

but

```
fraction = b/L          # only works if b is an array, not a list.
```

Looks like this is trying to turn all elements in `a` to float, but that's not how a python loop works.

```
for val in a:
    val = "{:.1f}".format(val)
    val = float(val)
```

`a = np.array(a)` will produce a float array, so there's no need for this loop.

Anyways, it looks like `kappa_i` is an array.  If so then the following demonstrates your error:

```
In [311]: kappa=[]
In [312]: kappa.append(np.arange(3))
In [313]: kappa
Out[313]: [array([0, 1, 2])]
In [314]: plt.plot([1,2,3], kappa)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-314-e15645b5613f>", line 1, in <module>
    plt.plot([1,2,3], kappa)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2988, in plot
    return gca().plot(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1605, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 315, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 501, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (3,) and (1, 3)
```

By using that list append, you made a list with one array element.  When passed to plot that is produces a (1,n) array.

Correct your code, whether it's the actual code or the copy to the question.  And pay closer attention to when variables are lists, or arrays, and if arrays, what's the `shape` and `dtype`.